# inputting in a multithreaded process

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking

Hey i am learning about networks and BSD sockets right now and i want to create a group chat.So after creating a multithreaded server(1 thread for each user) i have a question right now .

So basically my server works like this.Each threads waits for its client to send a massage then it sends to all other users in the chat.Now i am thinking do i have to make the client program 2 threaded.One thread will always wait for an massage from the server and the other one will wait for a user input.

But will it work??If i will just write in the second thread cin>>massage; Will everything be ok?

What if halfway through my input scheduler decides to give the CPU to the first thread.

Comment: Why not try it and see?  This is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You do not *have* to have a multi-threaded client.  You could but it is not required.

Look at [select()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) and [poll()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to see if your socket is ready to read from. For a single-threaded program, you just interleave your reads and writes when you have data ready and [sleep()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) or [sched_yield()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) the rest of the time.